# Node.js fs.readfile/Asynchronous file access: Get the current file in the callback

Tags: node.js, file, asynchronous, readfile, fs

I'm looking for a way to get information about the current written file in the callback, e. g. the full file name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naive way of doing this would be:

```
var filename = "/myfile.txt"
fs.readFile(filename, function(err, contents) { 
   console.log("Hey, I just read" + filename)
   if(err) 
     console.log("There was an error reading the file.")
   else
     console.log("File contents are " + contents)
})
```

The problem of above code is that if any other code has changed the `filename` variable by the time the callback of `fs.readFile` is called, the logged filename will be wrong.

Instead you should do:

```
var filename = "/myfile.txt"
fs.readFile(filename, makeInformFunction(filename))
function makeInformFunction(filename) {
  return function(err, contents) {
    console.log("Hey, I just read" + filename)
    if(err) 
      console.log("There was an error reading the file.")
    else
      console.log("File contents are " + contents)    
  }
}
```

Here, the `filename` variable becomes local to the `makeInformFunction` function, which makes the value of `filename` fixed for each particular invocation of this function. The `makeInformFunction` creates a new function with this fixed value for `filename`, which is then used as the callback.

Note that, `filename` within the `makeInformFunction` refers to a whole different variable than `filename` in the outer scope. In fact, because the argument name used in `makeInformFunction` uses the same name as the variable in the outer scope, this variable in the outer scope becomes entirely unreachable from within that function scope. If, for some reason, you want access to that outer variable, you need to choose a different argument name for the `makeInformFunction`.